# Flatten XML using XSLT but based on nesting level

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to write some XSLT that will flatten any given XML such that a new line occurs whenever the nesting level changes.  My input can be any XML document, with any number of nested levels so the structure isn't known to the XSLT.  Due to the tools available to me, my solution has to use XSLT version 1.0.

For example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <CUSTOMER_ID>0</CUSTOMER_ID>
    <NAME>Default Company</NAME>
    <BONUSES>
      <BONUSES_ROW>
        <BONUS_ID>21</BONUS_ID>
        <DESCRIPTION>Performance Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
      </BONUSES_ROW>
      <BONUSES_ROW>
        <BONUS_ID>26</BONUS_ID>
        <DESCRIPTION>Special Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
      </BONUSES_ROW>
    </BONUSES>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <CUSTOMER_ID>1</CUSTOMER_ID>
    <NAME>Dealer 1</NAME>
    <BONUSES>
      <BONUSES_ROW>
        <BONUS_ID>27</BONUS_ID>
        <DESCRIPTION>June Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
        <BONUS_VALUES>
          <BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
            <VALUE>10</VALUE>
            <PERCENT>N</PERCENT>
          </BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
          <BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
            <VALUE>11</VALUE>
            <PERCENT>Y</PERCENT>
          </BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
        </BONUS_VALUES>
      </BONUSES_ROW>
    </BONUSES>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

needs to becomes....

```
0, Default Company
21, Performance Bonus
26, Special Bonus
1, Dealer 1
27, June Bonus
10, N
11, Y
```

The XSLT I've written so far is...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> 
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
     <xsl:if test="position()!= last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test="position()= last()"><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>     
     <xsl:apply-templates select="./child::*"/>          
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but my output just isn't correct, with gaps and unnecessary data.

```
0,Default Company,
,21,Performance Bonus

26,Special Bonus
1,Dealer 1,

27,June Bonus,
,10,N

11,Y
```

It seems there needs to be a check as whether or not a node can contain text, but I'm stuck and could do with an XSLT expert's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test to see if an element has text by doing: `*[text()]`

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <CUSTOMER_ID>0</CUSTOMER_ID>
        <NAME>Default Company</NAME>
        <BONUSES>
            <BONUSES_ROW>
                <BONUS_ID>21</BONUS_ID>
                <DESCRIPTION>Performance Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
            </BONUSES_ROW>
            <BONUSES_ROW>
                <BONUS_ID>26</BONUS_ID>
                <DESCRIPTION>Special Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
            </BONUSES_ROW>
        </BONUSES>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <CUSTOMER_ID>1</CUSTOMER_ID>
        <NAME>Dealer 1</NAME>
        <BONUSES>
            <BONUSES_ROW>
                <BONUS_ID>27</BONUS_ID>
                <DESCRIPTION>June Bonus</DESCRIPTION>
                <BONUS_VALUES>
                    <BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
                        <VALUE>10</VALUE>
                        <PERCENT>N</PERCENT>
                    </BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
                    <BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
                        <VALUE>11</VALUE>
                        <PERCENT>Y</PERCENT>
                    </BONUS_VALUES_ROW>
                </BONUS_VALUES>
            </BONUSES_ROW>
        </BONUSES>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[text()]">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[text()])">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
0, Default Company
21, Performance Bonus
26, Special Bonus
1, Dealer 1
27, June Bonus
10, N
11, Y
```

Also, take a look at [Built-in Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) to see what makes this stylesheet work with only one template.

**EDIT**

This stylesheet will also output a comma for empty elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[text() or not(*)]">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[text() or not(*)])">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's a very elegant solution and achieves exactly what I wanted.  I read the Built-in Template Rules link thanks.  One more question, if I wanted to still output a comma for empty nodes that could contain text but don't, how would I do it? e.g. <ID>1</ID><NAME>Jo Smith</NAME><JOB_TITLE/><DOB>1980-12-01<DOB> => 1, Jo Smith, , 1980-12-01

Comment: @user2532750 - I think the only way to do that is to assume that any element that does not have a child could contain text. The way to test that is `not(*)` or `not(node())`. I've added an updated stylesheet as an example.

Comment: I used `*` instead of `node()` because if an element contains only comments/processing instructions, you most likely want to treat it as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check or validate your XML.

```
In your XML, Start Node <ROWSET> does not end with </ROWSET>

If  <ROWSET> node ends with </ROWSET> then, following XSL code will work for your expectation output
```

```
<xsl:template match="ROWSET">
    <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
        <xsl:value-of select="CUSTOMER_ID"/>, <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="BONUSES/BONUSES_ROW">
            <xsl:value-of select="BONUS_ID"/>, <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count(BONUS_VALUES/BONUS_VALUES_ROW)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$cnt &gt; 0">
                <xsl:for-each select="BONUS_VALUES/BONUS_VALUES_ROW">
                    <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>, <xsl:value-of select="PERCENT"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did ask for a generic solution, that would work with any XML.